# execution order finally() in promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

I was expecting the finally to run after resolving all promises, but I see that it runs after resolving the first promise. So I have two questions:
(1) Is the finally one per promise just like the catch, that is, can I have a finally per promise or because this behavior?
(2) If I need a finally to run after resolving all promises, do I need only one at the end, just like catch?

```
let variable = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            
            console.log('empiezo 1era promesa, espero 9');
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(1);
            }, 9000);
    })
    .finally(() => {

        console.log('empieza finally');
    })
    .then(data => {
        
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            
            console.log('1era promesa resulta, empiezo 2da promesa, espero 5 seg');
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(2);
            }, 5000);
        });
        
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('2da promesa resulta, ya termino todo');
        console.log(data);
    })
```

Ouput:
empiezo 1era promesa, espero 9
empieza finally
1era promesa resulta, empiezo 2da promesa, espero 5 seg
2da promesa resulta, ya termino todo
2

My doubt is because I always see examples with only one finally at the end and this one is executed after resolving all the promises.

Comment: `Promise.all()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Yes, `finally` is "one per promise" and is executed after a promise either resolves or rejects. So each promise in this chain can have its "own" `finally` and if you want something to be executed at the end of the chain regardless of resolve or reject, you have to add the finally at the end of the chain

Comment: thank you very much, all my doubts have been solved regarding the finally(). Just to confirm my knowledge, the catch() is also "one per promise" and if I want one that catches all errors I put it at the end, right? @derpirscher

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the `then`, `catch` and `finally` methods are "per promise", the promise they were called on. They all return a new promise that will resolve after the callback(s) have run, and they do not know about any other promises further down the chain (or even in other chains).

If you want your `finally` callback to run after all the promises in your chain have settled, you should also chain it in the end.